# Import data from mysql using JOIN in Sqoop

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

When I try to import data from mysql database using sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://100.107.57.141/mysql --username test -P --query 'SELECT FirstName, Education, Car_Details FROM emp e JOIN emp_test_new etn on e.id=etn.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by id  --target-dir /home/join
```

I am getting below error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE  (1 =
> 0)' at line 1
>
> 17/08/05 12:04:25 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter

Comment: What is in `$CONDITIONS`?

Comment: Where I have to mention conditions, if I am executing in command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `(` near `JOIN  ON` condition.

Correct sytnatx:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://100.107.57.141/mysql --username test -P \
--query "SELECT e.FirstName, e.Education, e.Car_Details \
FROM emp e JOIN emp_test_new etn ON (e.id == etn.id) \
WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by id  --target-dir /home/join
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter.
```

use the below command for the above error:

```
 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```